# Convert Rails Datetime to YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I have ann app that has a start_date and an end_date that is currently in the format `Thu, 23 Apr 2015 17:00:00 UTC +00:00` and the field type is datetime.

I am needing to convert it into this `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ` for the Eventbrite API but I am having little luck.

I have tried `iso = Time.iso8601(start_date)` but I get the following error `TypeError: no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String`

Anyone able to point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You want to use it as an instance method `start_date.iso8601`. The class method [expects a String](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-xmlschema)

Comment: hey Lee that works great if you add an answer I shall accept it.

Comment: I'll let G.B take the upvotes :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try following:

```
start_date.iso8601
```

**output**

```
=> "2015-05-06T15:53:51+05:00"
```